# How to run more than one outer loop at time?

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a way for me to to run the outer loops simultaneously without mess with the inner loops?

I'm loosing the data.table performance if I use loops this way?

**Note:** I know there is some data.table functions that makes combinations like ones that I made, but they don't work for what I'm planning to do.

```
library(data.table)
library(MASS)
data(Insurance)
x <- setDT(Insurance)
names(x) <- tolower(names(x))
x[,`:=`(district_group = 'A')][district == 1 | district == 4, `:=` (district_group = 'B')]
vars <- c('group','age')
comb <- do.call("c", lapply(seq_along(vars), function(i) combn(vars, i, FUN = list)))
comb[[length(comb)+1]] <- character(0)
d <- c('district','district_group')

tmp <- list()

for(i in seq_along(d)){
  for(j in seq_along(comb)){
    y <- copy(x)
    y <- y[,.(nclaims=sum(claims), region = d[i]), by = c(d[i],comb[[j]])]
    setnames(y,old = d[i], new = 'region_id')
    tmp[[j]] <- y
    
  }
  if(i==1){
    tbl <- rbindlist(tmp, fill = TRUE)
  }
  if(i > 1){
    tbl <- rbindlist(list(tbl, rbindlist(tmp, fill = TRUE)), fill = TRUE)
  }
}

for(j in seq_along(tbl)){
  set(tbl, which(is.na(tbl[[j]])),j,'#')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach using `foreach` & `doParallel`

```r
library(data.table)
library(MASS)
library(foreach)

data(Insurance)
x <- setDT(Insurance)
names(x) <- tolower(names(x))
x[,`:=`(district_group = 'A')][district == 1 | district == 4, `:=` (district_group = 'B')]
vars <- c('group','age')
comb <- do.call("c", lapply(seq_along(vars), function(i) combn(vars, i, FUN = list)))
comb[[length(comb)+1]] <- character(0)
d <- c('district','district_group')

# as foreach return a list of df I wrap them in rbindlist which combine all the 
# df in list into one data.table
tbl <- rbindlist(foreach(i = seq_along(d)) %do% {
  tmp <- list()
  for(j in seq_along(comb)){
    y <- copy(x)
    y <- y[,.(nclaims=sum(claims), region = d[i]), by = c(d[i],comb[[j]])]
    setnames(y,old = d[i], new = 'region_id')
    tmp[[j]] <- y
    
  }
  
  tbl <- rbindlist(tmp, fill = TRUE)
  
  tbl
})

for(j in seq_along(tbl)){
  set(tbl, which(is.na(tbl[[j]])),j,'#')
}
```

Here is the output

```r
tbl
#>      region_id  group nclaims         region   age
#>   1:         1    <1l     249       district     #
#>   2:         1 1-1.5l     636       district     #
#>   3:         1 1.5-2l     378       district     #
#>   4:         1    >2l     118       district     #
#>   5:         2    <1l     150       district     #
#>  ---                                              
#> 146:         A    >2l      17 district_group 25-29
#> 147:         A    >2l      20 district_group 30-35
#> 148:         A    >2l      90 district_group   >35
#> 149:         B      #    1707 district_group     #
#> 150:         A      #    1444 district_group     #
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

If this confirmed what you wanted then you can run the for-loop parallel using `doParallel` package as following

```r
library(data.table)
library(MASS)
library(doParallel)

# register parallel cores
registerDoParallel(detectCores())
# running outerloop in parallel using foreach & %dopar%
tbl <- rbindlist(foreach(i = seq_along(d)) %dopar% {
  tmp <- list()
  for(j in seq_along(comb)){
    y <- copy(x)
    y <- y[,.(nclaims=sum(claims), region = d[i]), by = c(d[i],comb[[j]])]
    setnames(y,old = d[i], new = 'region_id')
    tmp[[j]] <- y
    
  }
  
  tbl <- rbindlist(tmp, fill = TRUE)
  
  tbl
})

for(j in seq_along(tbl)){
  set(tbl, which(is.na(tbl[[j]])),j,'#')
}

tbl
#>      region_id  group nclaims         region   age
#>   1:         1    <1l     249       district     #
#>   2:         1 1-1.5l     636       district     #
#>   3:         1 1.5-2l     378       district     #
#>   4:         1    >2l     118       district     #
#>   5:         2    <1l     150       district     #
#>  ---                                              
#> 146:         A    >2l      17 district_group 25-29
#> 147:         A    >2l      20 district_group 30-35
#> 148:         A    >2l      90 district_group   >35
#> 149:         B      #    1707 district_group     #
#> 150:         A      #    1444 district_group     #
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

A quick comparison multiply original x data by 1000 times

Your code

```r
   user  system elapsed 
 26.046   8.298  19.034
```

The code with `foreach` & `%do%`

```
   user  system elapsed 
 28.471   8.128  20.577
```

The code with `foreach` & `%dopar%`

```
   user  system elapsed 
  0.058   0.081  15.413
```

Comment: can you provide some speed comparison output with and without `doParallel` ?

Comment: Just added a quick system.time of the code

Comment: thanks, I will read the documentation of this library. just a doubt, why I got this error `Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "copy"` even with data.table loaded?

Comment: I am not sure. it should work fine if all you library is loaded before trigger `foreach` loop. The `doParallel` will replicate your current environment to cluster so all the loaded library will be loaded in cluster environment and each cluster is independent from each other and parent cluster. Because of this replicate mechanism this approach could cost a lot of memory.